# -webkit-transform - Is it possible to remove element from memory on iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, webkit, transform

I'm building memory intensive stuff on the iPad, using a lot of webkit transforms to do complex animations. I'm wondering if it's possible to remove an element from memory by taking the webkit transform off or clearing it somehow.

Is it possible to remove element from memory using something like:

```
... .style.webkitTransform = ''
```

or, if transform is set using a class, could removing the class take the element out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the line

```
  document.getElementById("//id").style.webkitTransform = '';
```

will remove any transform data. ('none' is the default webkitTransform value, but the empty string works fine).

See here for more info: http://cubiq.org/testing-memory-usage-on-mobile-safari